# Rails request where relation created_at lower than?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to select all `Authors` where `Comments` and `Posts` `created_at` lower than `some time`

```
Author.include(:comments, :posts).
       where(comments: { created_at < 8.hours,ago}, posts: { created_at< 8.hours.ago } )`
```

The author may not have any comments or posts. How can I do that?

Comment: This guide should cover 95% of your querying needs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: Do you want the authors without comments and posts to be included or excluded from the selection? Also, should the selection find authors who have _both_ recent comments _and_ recent posts, or who have at least one recent comment _or_ recent post?

Comment: If `Author` created more than duration time ago they should be included

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can find recently created objects in any particular model:

```
Model.where(created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.current)
```

Perhaps that can help in some way

Comment: While this code snippet might answer the question, it is better to include some explanation with it, to help people understand what it's doing and why it helps solve the original problem.

Comment: `Author.include(:comments, :posts).
       where(comments: { created_at: 8.hours.ago..Time.current}, posts: { created_at: 8.hours.ago..Time.current } )`

Comment: But `Author` can have only `Posts`, or only `Comments`

Comment: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html

check this